# Convert time entered from excel file to gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datetime, gridview

I have an excel file where I am adding time in the format- **"10:14:16"** and added code

```
dt = ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateDataTable(FilePath, "abc");
```

to convert and display this excel file in a gridview in asp.net. It shows the value as **"0.426574074074074"**.

I am unable to save this data in the sql server database as I need the format to be same as mentioned in excel file. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It is a OA-Date. OA Date means a date stored on a computer in OLE Automation format.  You can use `double.Parse` to get a double from the string and `DateTime.FromOADate` to parse it to `DateTime`:

```
string date = "0.426574074074074";
double num;
if (double.TryParse(date, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out num))
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(num);
    // 12/30/1899 10:14:16
    // use DateTime.TimeOfday to get the TimeSpan:
    TimeSpan ts = dt.TimeOfDay; // 10:14:16
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [DateTime.FromOADate(double date)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it returns a DateTime equivalent to the specified OLE Automation Date.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(double.Parse(stringVariableContainingDateTime));
```

> The d parameter is a double-precision floating-point number that
>   represents a date as the number of days before or after the base date,
>   midnight, 30 December 1899. The sign and integral part of d encode the
>   date as a positive or negative day displacement from 30 December 1899,
>   and the absolute value of the fractional part of d encodes the time of
>   day as a fraction of a day displacement from midnight. d must be a
>   value between negative 657435.0 through positive 2958465.99999999, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).